# Blender curve shape glitch/problem

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm not completely sure if it's the curve but these random line figures keep appearing in the background and I don't want it. They're the ones with no vertices.

[image]

[Higher resolution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BXL7.jpg)

Comment: The vertices were on the bigger object on the screen, I was on object mode. ;-;

Comment: pls upload your file